# Two Search bars on one page in magento

Tags: magento, search

I am working on one website where I want to integrate Magento default search two times on a page. I have **two search fields and want to search from two stores**. Is that possible ?

I can do that for one store and default Magento also support one store at a time. If someone suggest some hints or guidelines it will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to seach box two time in page...???

Comment: @AmitBera yes exactly.

Comment: have any search box in page???

Comment: @AmitBera But how with different stores ? means they will search same items but i want to search different item for each one.Hope you got my point

Answer (score 0):

you try the blog file using below code...

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
?>
```

Comment: Did you get my question ?

Comment: call the code serial times in page according to your position

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to change the store view using a querystring parameter in the search action.  Replace `YOUR_STORE` below with the store view code you're wanting to search.  This will take you to the search results of the other store.

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?___store=YOUR_STORE" method="get">
<div class="form-search">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search entire store here...');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('/index.php/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
</form>
```

If you wanted to integrate both sets of search results into one search results page then that would require some additional coding.